What test should I use for Weighted Mean Proportions?
I want to know if the "weighted mean proportion" of a racial group in the organization (overall) is significantly different from the "weighted mean proportion" of the group within departments.
I have the group's proportion across 30 organizations at two levels: (a) the level of the organization overall and (b) the level of the Marketing department (within these organizations).
I created two objects -- one for each level.
prop.Overall <- c(45.60, 38.98, 39.15, 40.09, 42.71, 44.68, 
                        43.43, 44.68, 45.60, 45.76, 45.85, 46.11, 
                        46.98, 47.83, 42.71, 49.22, 45.60, 51.54, 
                        53.08, 42.71, 56.67, 56.88, 57.54, 57.93, 
                        42.71, 63.13, 63.23, 66.25, 68.34, 68.42)

Each entry above is the proportion of the racial group at a distinct organization. (total of 30 organizations).
I do something similar below, but for the group's proportion at the level of the Marketing Department at these 30 organizations.
prop.in.Mktg <- c(40.78, 32.36, 41.33, 32.36, 28.11, 28.11, 
                    29.93, 28.11, 32.03, 44.12, 38.22, 28.87, 
                    27.19, 46.44, 41.93, 32.36, 32.99, 32.36, 
                    49.12, 32.36, 41.33, 39.55, 45.08, 42.23, 
                    35.45, 41.33, 41.33, 30.28, 26.65, 36.61)

Using these two objects, I can easily find the frequencies, unique entries, and do weights, and then calculate the group's weighted average proportion at both levels.
My questions: (these may seem silly to the experts, but here goes:)
a) In this particular case, (Remember: I want to know if the "weighted mean proportion" of a racial group in the organization (overall) is significantly different from the "weighted mean proportion" of the group within a department...) -- am I doing a statistical test with means or a test with proportions? Somehow this seems more complicated to me than it should be. (I am inclined to do a "One-Proportion Z-Test" -- would that be correct here?)
b) If I am using "weighted mean proportions", does that require the use of "weighted SEs" (around the weighted mean proportion) as well? or would the typical standard errors be just fine?
NOTE: this is just a minimal example, of course. The differential weights do matter in the full data, it's important that we use a weighted mean proportion for comparisons. And then we have to repeat the same test for several other departments besides Marketing.
Any clarification regarding what test to use here is greatly appreciated.
